# Robobrowser and flask errors

Tags: python, forms, beautifulsoup, robobrowser

I am trying to create a script for myself to use on a few classified sites and starting with cl, I am using flask web framework and robobrowser but not going so well.

***The Goal*** It will take my preset values and put them in the fields from that classifieds websites. Doesnt seem like a difficult concept however after 5 hours of reading online different code and trial and error I remembered the best developers are on stack...

I should inform you I am new to Python and still have alot to learn so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error I get is:
assert isinstance(form, 'str')
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

but I dont see how to fix this and completely lost. HELP!!!
thanks in advance

```
# autosubmit to site

            from flask import Flask
            from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

            app = Flask(__name__)

            @app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
            class My_RoboBrowser(RoboBrowser):
                def __init__(self, auth=None, parser=None, headers=None, user_agent=None, history=True):
                    RoboBrowser.__init__(self, parser=None, user_agent=None, history=True)

                def Open(self, vURL, vVerify=True):
                    response = self.session.get(vURL, verify=vVerify)
                    self._update_state(response)

            browser = My_RoboBrowser(RoboBrowser, "html.parser");
            urlL = 'https://accounts.craigslist.org/login'

            browser.Open(urlL)

            form = browser.get_form(id='login')
            assert isinstance(form, 'str')
            form['username'] = 'username'
            form['password'] = 'password'
            browser.submit_form(form)

            urlQ = 'https://post.craigslist.org/k/qGDv7K4q5RGD0B5ZEBgXOQ/GLzgd?s=edit'
            browser.open(urlQ)

            #Question_Tag = browser.find_all(class_="not_answered")[0]

            #ID = Question_Tag.get('data-qid')

            #Get the form to fill out
            Form = browser.get_form(id='formpost')
            Form['PostingTitle'].value = 'Create this advertise ment in py'
            Form['Postal_code'].value = ['10543']
            Form['PostingBody'].value = 'TOGETHER WE INNOVATE Stress free communication with developers that are in the United States. We pride ourselves in bringing your web and app ideas to life and keeping your data secured'
            browser.submit_form(Form)


            if __name__ == "__main__":
                app.run()
```

Comment: `isinstance(form, str)` see? `str` not `'str'`

Comment: @mehtunguh I removed those quotes and still getting an error    'assert isinstance(form, str)
AssertionError '

Comment: `AssertionError` in this case means the object is not an instance of `str`. Your code is correct, but your form is not a string. It looks like it might be a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

isinstance returns true if the first argument is an instance (or subclass) of the second argument otherwise false. In your assertion the form variable is of type robobrowser.forms.form.Form. You can see this with the following code:

```
print(type(form)) # should print <class 'robobrowser.forms.form.Form'>
```

Your particular assertion will pass if you update the second argument to indicate this robobrowser Form class:

```
# Add the following to your imports
import robobrowser

# ... existing code below imports

# The following should be true if form is valid
assert isinstance(form, robobrowser.forms.form.Form)
```

You can also import the Form class directly but you'll have to update the assertion accordingly:

```
from robobrowser.forms.form import Form

# ... existing code below imports

assert isinstance(form, Form)
```

**Edit:**

Below is the code to properly get the form from that page. There are no forms with an id of 'login' but you can select it by using its action or grabbing the first form on the page.

```
# ... previous code ...

form = browser.get_form(action='https://accounts.craigslist.org/login')
# you can also use: form = browser.get_form(0)

# It looks like you aren't selecting the fields by their proper names either.
form['inputEmailHandle'] = 'fill in username here'
form['inputPassword'] = 'fill in password here'
browser.submit_form(form)
```

See if the added code above helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply I did do as you said above however now I get this error `form['username'] = 'user'

TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment `

Comment: It looks like you aren't selecting the form correctly on that page. None of forms on that page have an id of 'login'. You can also select the form by its action instead of id. Try using *form = browser.get_form(action='https://accounts.craigslist.org/login')* or even *form = browser.get_form(0)*. I'll edit my answer above.

Comment: thank you so much for all your help. So I did what you said and changed the action link, as well as the inputs and I dont know how I ended up doing that wrong. So it appears that it is logging me in but I can't tell because nothing pops up. I thought it would pop up the link, sign in than take me to the posting URL but its not is that even possible with Python?

Comment: now I get this error:                                           
` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/learning/PycharmProjects/Mobile-SE/sas.py", line 38, in <module>
    form['PostingTitle'].value = 'Create your dream web, mobile or desktop application'
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\robobrowser\forms\form.py", line 213, in __getitem__
    return self.fields[item]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 717, in __getitem__
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400: Bad Request`

Comment: I checked Ids were correct & URLs  
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/learning/PycharmProjects/Mobile-SE/sas.py", line 38, in <module>
    form['PostingTitle'].value = 'Create your dream web, mobile or desktop application'
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\robobrowser\forms\form.py", line 213, in __getitem__
    return self.fields[item]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 717, in __getitem__
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400: Bad Request**